# iOS: Poor performance with CAGradientLayer

Tags: ios, performance, calayer, frame-rate, cagradientlayer

I'm using a class method to return a CAGradientLayer and insert it into a sublayer in a view. If I set the frame to a quarter of the screen size, width and height, my application runs smooth as butter, but most of the time if I set the frame size to the full width and height, the smoothness of the animation takes a big hit.

I found that most of the time when the animation smoothness is ruined, I can load in a large set of images, and even though the CAGradientLayer still exists, the smoothness is restored. This makes me think that the act of loading in images triggers the OS to empty some kind of cache. Is there anything that comes to mind that can be emptied manually?

Would somehow setting the size of the CAGradientLayer to something small and then stretching it out help even if I was to lose quality?

Before the CAGradientLayer is returned, I also tried setting these properties with little or no effect to the problem:

```
headerLayer.shouldRasterize = YES;

headerLayer.rasterizationScale=[UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

headerLayer.drawsAsynchronously = YES;

headerLayer.opaque = YES;
```